# Can't see the floating menu of virtualbox virtual machine!

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit as guest on Windows 7 64 bit. Everything is fine except one thing..when take my mouse pointer near the top edge(I set it at top) can't get the floating menu of virtual box in full screen mode...so I'm not able to minimize my Ubuntu virtual machine. Even worse the ctrl,alt+tab combination to switch out of windows is also not working.

I'm also running Linux Mint 13 Mate as guset where everything is fine so i guess this an Ubuntu problem may be related to compiz etc stuff.

Virtual Box version : 4.2.6

EDIT: guest additions are installed. Before installing additions Ubuntu was running in 1024x768 and now in full wide screen. As far as I remember the floating menu was available when guest additions were not installed.

thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions in Ubuntu?

Comment: yes...see the edit above

Comment: Have you double-checked Settings under Machine > Settings > General > Advanced > Mini Toolbar?

Comment: yep...same as for the linux mint machine and I also have crunchbang linux and it also has the same settings. Both of which have visible floating menu

Answer (score 3):

This is still a problem/bug and is references in the VirtualBox bug tracker here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9775

**There is a work-around!**

While in fullscreen mode in VirtualBox, log out of Ubuntu. When the login screen appears, you should be able to either see the mini-tool bar or you can press the HOST+Home keys to make it visible and it should show up.

I'm running Mint 17 x64 as my guest on my Win7 x64 host. I have the exact same issue with the fullscreen mini-tool bar, but logging out of Mint makes the toolbar appear. Strangely, when I move the fullscreen to my second monitor and log back in, the mini-tool now becomes visible whilst in the desktop environment.

**Also**:
Ubuntu uses Unity and for me Mint uses Cinnamon, both of which are 3D accelerated Desktop Environments. Maybe MATE is not, which is why it works. If you turn of 3D Acceleration in the VBox settings for your guest, the mini-tool bar should work, but then you'll be in software rendering mode in Ubuntu Unity or Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, but for me the `<right Ctrl> + F` hotkey still works. It will bring the screen back to Windowed view.

Comment: yes this works but it is not efficient. BTW your answer should be a comment

Comment: Nope, it's not.. but it seems to be a VirtualBox bug so might be worth to report it to them too. 

Ow sorry, didn't know. Why should it be a comment actually? It is an answer to your question after all..

Answer (score 0):

**solved**

I have encountered the same problem after installing guest additions in my ubuntu. Do the following steps :

- log into your OS which will be stretched or full screened most probably.
- make sure your guest additions are activated.
- press right Ctrl + F to bring up the windowed mode and you will see the toolbar there at the bottom or at top according to your settings made in the virtual box.
- go to display settings from there and click on auto resize and the  make it full screen.

Now you can see your toolbar along with full screen OS.